# How do I get my question featured on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, bountied-tab

What are the questions in the 'featured' tab on the Stack Overflow `Questions` page?

How does a question become 'featured'? Is it just a list of questions with active bounties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are simply questions with a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) set.

Comment: Thank you! Shouldn't this be in the faq? Or is it and I missed it?

Comment: It probably should be. There is a FAQ-tagged question on meta that explains how to set a bounty (I just added a link).